# ListView to hold LinearLayouts

Tags: android

Is it possible for a ListView to hold LinearLayouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!

You will have to write your own custom adapter and then overwrite the getView() method.

A good example for this can be found here - http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/